# From postman to spring boot authorization header is not null, where angular to spring boot the authorization header is null

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

Error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Angular service:

```
getUsersList(): Observable<User[]>{ 
        return this.httpClient.get<User[]>(`${this.baseUrl}`);
    }
```

Inceptor:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest,  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthenticationService } from './auth-service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
    const jwtToken = this.authService.getJwt();
    
    if(jwtToken){
      const header = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwtToken)
      });
      console.log(header);
      return next.handle(header);
    }

    return next.handle(req);

  }
}
```

In the request the token is valid.

Spring boot CORS:

```
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("**")
                .exposedHeaders("Authorization")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
```

Filter:

```
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests()
                //.requestMatchers("/test").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/login/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/authenticate/get-jwt").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/users/**").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/user/address/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.authenticationEntryPoint(point))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
```

Getting header null.

Comment: Is the method you are calling from angular side is a GET API annotated on Spring boot side ?

Answer (score 0):

By applying corsConfigur in httpSecurity, the problem is solved:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeRequests()
            //.requestMatchers("/test").authenticated()
            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/login/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/authenticate/get-jwt").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/bulk-transaction/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/users/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/user/address/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.authenticationEntryPoint(point))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .apply(corsConfigurer());
    http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}

private CorsConfigurer<HttpSecurity> corsConfigurer() {
    return new CorsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>()
            .configurationSource(request -> {
                CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
                corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin("http://10.11.201.189:4200");
                corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("*");
                corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("*");
                corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(true);
                return corsConfig;
            });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).